# How did they bake the showbread in the desert

Tags: parshanut-torah-comment

B"H

If they had no flour what did they use to bake it? The mawn? If so, whose portion of the mawn was used? Aharoyn's? Other koyhawneem?  Did a unique portion fall just for it? Sources would be great

Comment: https://www.sefaria.org.il/sheets/260369?lang=he

Comment: @IsraelReader thanks for the source, I probably wouldnt have known how to find that, I don't think it mentions whose portion of the mawn was used (according to the opinion who said they grinded it for it etc) do you know of any other sources, or ways to find them?

Comment: @IsraelReader Wow!